# Plot gridded map starting from cells

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
yr mo dy hr   lon   lat  cell   sst  avg     moavg
1900  1 29 17 -73.5 -59.5 10907 6.0 3.299048  6.00
1900  1 28 17 -72.5 -58.5 11268 6.4 3.928571  6.40
1900  1 25 17 -74.5 -57.5 11626 6.7 4.748500  6.70
1900  1 21 17 -73.5 -57.5 11627 6.8 4.569398  6.75
1900  1 22 17 -73.5 -57.5 11627 6.7 4.569398  6.75
1900  1 18 17 -70.5 -57.5 11630 6.6 4.385753  6.60
```

and I want to plot a map with the value of moavg for every cell. The problem is that I don't know how to pass the plot function the lon and lat value of the corresponding cell.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the `image` function perhaps? `image(DF$lon, DF$lat, DF$moavg)`

Comment: I get the error increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

Comment: `image` expects a matrix as its third argument, which is why you can't just pass `DF$moavg`. Building the matrix is not so tough, though (see my answer).

Comment: ah yes sorry I forgot that...I always forget that.

Answer (score 4):

The `image` function will x- and y-values as well as a matrix of values to be plotted. Therefore, you'll need to convert your data into a matrix of plot values (with `NA` for the missing elements):

```
# Load the data frame
df <- read.table(text="yr mo dy hr   lon   lat  cell   sst  avg     moavg
1900  1 29 17 -73.5 -59.5 10907 6.0 3.299048  6.00
1900  1 28 17 -72.5 -58.5 11268 6.4 3.928571  6.40
1900  1 25 17 -74.5 -57.5 11626 6.7 4.748500  6.70
1900  1 21 17 -73.5 -57.5 11627 6.8 4.569398  6.75
1900  1 22 17 -73.5 -57.5 11627 6.7 4.569398  6.75
1900  1 18 17 -70.5 -57.5 11630 6.6 4.385753  6.60", header=T)

# Compute the ordered x- and y-values
lon <- sort(unique(df$lon))
lat <- sort(unique(df$lat))

# Build the matrix to be plotted
moavg <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(lon), ncol=length(lat))
moavg[cbind(match(df$lon, lon), match(df$lat, lat))] <- df$moavg

# Plot the image
image(lon, lat, moavg)
```

[image: Heat map]

Comment: @user3036416 sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. What are you looking for?