# Image vs ggplot: how to plot color legend?

Tags: r, image, plot, ggplot2, legend

Hi I have a matrix 37x73 that represent one variable (moavg) gridded with a 10x10 deg spacing (-180< LON< 180 e -90 < LAT< 90). I am able to plot it using image

```
image(LON, LAT, moavg)
```

but I can't display the colour bar. I would like to know if there is another function to do that (maybe ggplot) that allows me also to plot the colour legend.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For plotting gridded spatial data, the `raster` and `rasterVis` packages are also useful.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
library(rasterVis) # this will also load the raster package

# Create a raster from a matrix of dummy data
m <- matrix(runif(36*18), ncol=36)
r <- raster(m)

# Set the extent of the object
extent(r) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)

# plot with raster
plot(r)

# plot with rasterVis
levelplot(r, margin=FALSE)
```

If your gridded data exists in a file (e.g. .asc, .tif, etc.), then you can load it by giving `raster()` a file path, e.g. `raster('C:/path/to/moavg.asc')`, and you shouldn't need to set the extent in that case since the file should contain this metadata.

See `?raster` and `?levelplot` for more details.

**Plotting with `raster`**
[image: raster plot example]

**Plotting with `levelplot`**
[image: levelplot example]

---

**EDIT**

To address the extension to this question found in the comments, here is one way to overlay a polygon:

```
library(maps)
levelplot(r, xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude', margin=FALSE,
            panel = function(x, y, ...) {
              panel.levelplot(x, y,  ...)
              mp <- map("world", plot = FALSE, fill=TRUE)
              lpolygon(mp$x, mp$y)
            })
```

[image: levelplot with overlay]

Comment: Hi, that is great! How can I set the axes names and overlay a world map? I tried with map(add=T) bat it is not working..

Comment: Hi, what about instead to scale the map according to the spacing of the gridded field? Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Maybe post it as a new question if you can't find a relevant answer on SO. If you're asking how to adjust the points at which the legend changes colours, then use the `at` argument to supply a vector of numbers (as described under `?lattice::levelplot`).

Comment: Hi I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699809/scale-world-map-in-r

Answer (score 4):

With regards to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631677/plot-gridded-map-starting-from-cells):

```
library(fields)
image.plot(lon, lat, moavg, col=heat.colors(8))
```

[image]

PS: Please be so kind to provide a reproducible example in your question. [Here's how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).